# Azure IoT Hub Metrics

Tags: azure

Can anyone explain the difference between two Azure IoT hub metrics:

`dailyMessageQuotaUsed` and `d2c.telemetry.ingress.success`

[This document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-metrics) describes the former as

> Number of total messages used today. This is a cumulative value that
>   is reset to zero at 00:00 UTC every day.

and the latter as

> Number of device-to-cloud telemetry messages sent successfully to your
>   IoT hub

Surely then, measured over a day (00:00 to 00:00 UTC) these figures should agree.  My ingress.success messages seem to be 50% of dailyMessageQuotaUsed